# Keeping selection when using UITableViewRowActions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I've noticed this when using `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` or the default editing delete button. When a cell is swiped to show the action menu, the `UITableView` seems to **deselect** the currently selected cell(s) automatically.

Is there any way to disable this behavior, and keep the selection even while this menu is open? `tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing` does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TB;NOA (Too bad no one answered). I ended up using an `NSArray` to keep track of what was selected.